# Flexboxで中に二つのボックスがある場合、どちらのボックスに干渉せず真ん中に線を引きたい

Tags: html, css

flex-boxを使ってサイズがバラバラな二つの箱があった場合、中にあるboxにどちらも干渉せず、ちょうど真ん中にborderラインを引きたい場合どうしたら良いでしょうか？

**html**

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="red-box"></div>
  <div class="yellow-box"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
.flex-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.red-box {
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
.yellow-box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**やったこと**
・真ん中に新しい `div` タグを作ってcssで `hieght: 100%` でborderラインを `1px` でやって見た

※注意 `.red-box` に `border-light: solid 1px;` 、 `.yellow-box`に `border-left: solid 1px;` は線の長さが固定できないので使用できません。親要素のflex-boxの高さに合わせて線が引きたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: Flex-Boxの画像]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flex コンテナの [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/::before), [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/::after) 疑似要素で[絶対配置](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/position)を使い、 flex コンテナに対する[相対配置](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/position)を行うことで、質問者さんのやりたいことが実現出来ます。

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.red-box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow-box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.flex-box::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: blue;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="red-box"></div>
  <div class="yellow-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: supaさんありがとうございます! なるほどそうするんですね...。なかなか難しいですね。

Answer (score 0):

supaさんをのcssを元に少し調べて見たのですが、画面全体を分けたいときはsupaさんのcssを、flexのcontenerの中だけを真ん中に分けたいときは自分のcssをお使いください。`align-self:stretch;`で子要素のboxに何もなくてもいっぱいまで広がってくれるみたいです。みなさんありがとうございました。supaさん、本当にありがとうございます。

```css
.line-box {
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    align-self:stretch;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

※注意:  このcssは、htmlファイルの`.red-box`と`.yellow-box`の間に`<div class="line-box></div>`を追加したものです。